# High read/write data storage

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I'm designing a short-linking service. When people click one of my shortlinks I want to collect some data like ip address, useragent etc and then forward them on their destination. What would be the best way to store this data if my links table grows into the tens of millions. I'm not sure whether to use sql of something like elastic search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite opinion-based question, but I will try to answer.
The performance of your operations depends mainly on what kind of queries you are going to have. So the real question is **what do you want to do with this data** ? Some concepts, when dealing with a big amount of data follows:

#### Bulk Insert

In case you have to save a big amount of data records with one request, both **RDBMSs** and **elasticsearch** offer you the means to achieve that. ([postgreSQL populate data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/populate.html), [elasticsearch Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html))

#### Data Partitioning

If you deal with a huge amount of data, that is constantly getting bigger, the execution time of the queries can grow as the amount of data grows. At some point, you might realize, that you need to apply [data partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(database)).

With **elasticsearch** you can create [time-based-indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html): you can save this "traffic-analytics" into indices like 2018-03-traffic, 2018-04-traffic, etc.. Then you could refer to them under one name using [aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html). Please refer to [what-are-aliases-in-elasticsearch-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907041/what-are-aliases-in-elasticsearch-for/48908216#48908216) question.
**Postgres**, that also offers you the means for [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

So far so good, let's see some other aspects:

#### Data Structure

1. Does your schema consist of **strong predefined, complcated rules**?

   If not(and I think that is your case), you could use elasticsearch.
2. Would you need in the future to **add/remove fields** into/from your
   existing schema?

   Elasticsearch is more flexible accepting new fields in an existing index-you actually don't need to do anything-, where in a RDMS you should manage it yourself-aka update the table definition.

#### Opinion based conclusion

The above described assumption and the assumption, that you would like at some point to run data analytics and visualize them, leads me to conclude, that elasticsearch could be a better fit in your case. With [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana), you get this out of the box.

Notes: 
*1. I use PostgreSQL for the given RDBMS links, because I am familiar with that.*
*2. You should also consider the [Scalability](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194340/why-are-nosql-databases-more-scalable-than-sql) of RDBMS vs elasticsearch.*

Comment: Thank you very much or the details answer @Eirini. My main concern is to keep search times down. I want to be able to find the forwarding link from the incoming uri as fast as possible.

Comment: It depends on the writes, too ( If you have to do those simultaneously with the reads :)  Anyways if you use correct indexing and proper system tuning, you can achieve your goal with both of your alternatives. I hope, I helped somehow